# Use libcurl to list the directory on server. The server give only date of file time, not detail time

Tags: c, libcurl

I tried to use libcurl to list the directory on server by downloadBuffer method

```
resetOptions();

if (headerBuffer)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, write_response);
    curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, headerBuffer);
}

curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_URL, SV_PathA (m_header.c_str()).add(remotefile).get());
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_response);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);

curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);


/* Now run off and do what you've been told! */
int code = curl_easy_perform(m_curl);

if (postquotelist)
    curl_slist_free_all(postquotelist); 
if(CURLE_OK != code)
{
    setError(code,m_errorBuffer);
    return false;
}

  return true;
```

It worked well except one problem.
The server give only date of file time, not detail time.
For example, here was a line
drwxr-xr-x 3 compurxc compurxc  4096 Nov23 2012.
And there were many such lines.

I can get the filename, filesize but the lastmod time is only a date.
How can I use libcurl to switch the server to give detail lastmod time?

Many thanks,

Best regards,
Kelvin Gan

Comment: The only way this would be possible would be if the server offered URL parameters that changed how it formatted its directory listing.  The most common servers offer no such parameters.

Comment: You could perhaps use a HEAD request for each individual file to get a more detailed timestamp for it, but that too is not guaranteed (the relevant response header is not mandatory).

Comment: I did not see anything in particular about this code that was `C++` so I have recoded it just `C`